# SwiftUI + Realm: Deleting row of List crash, index is out of bounds

Tags: swiftui, realm, swiftui-list

When using onDelete as I am below, I can remove all rows successfully but only if I work backwards from the last row. If I remove any other rows I get a crash with the below message. Is there a way to help the rows update their position so they are not out of index?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 2 is out of bounds (must be less than 2).'
```

```
@EnvironmentObject var realmManager: RealmManager
    
@ObservedSectionedResults(Qualifier.self,
                          sectionKeyPath: \.isCustom,
                          sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "isCustom", ascending: false),
                                            SortDescriptor(keyPath: "isPremium", ascending: true),
                                            SortDescriptor(keyPath: "title", ascending: true)]) var qualifiers

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(qualifiers) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.id ? "Custom" : "Default")) {
                ForEach(section) { qualifier in
                    Text(qualifier.title)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    do {
                        guard let realm = realmManager.localRealm else { return }
                        guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
                                
                        try realm.write {
                            realm.delete(section[index])
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error deleting qualifier: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Qualifier: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: String
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var isPremium: Bool
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var isCustom: Bool
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var title: String
}
```

Comment: My guess is the Realm objects are being mapped/stored in an array at some point. Possibly with this `ObservedSectionedResults` - so when the object is deleted from realm, it's not deleted from the array so then the array does not match what's in Realm. That can be avoided by using Realm collection objects only as when an object is removed from Realm, it's also removed from the collection and the view is refreshed. That keeps everything sync'd up.